# Variable not working on div created in jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, variables, dynamic, global

This is simple code which works fine, but I want to figure it out how to set a variable for `novy.fadeIn(2000)`. 
For example one day will my js file had 300 lines and I want to change variable from one place -> `fadeIn` to `fadeOut` or something like that.

```
    var novy = $('<div/>', {id:'namaste'});
            var text = {textAlign : 'center', color : '#fff', fontSize: 'xx-large'}
   // var example = novy.fadeIn(2000) this is not working
        novy.appendTo('body').text('this code is .ITCHI.').css(text).hide();

        $(document).on('click', function(){
            novy.fadeIn(2000); // example;
        })
```

For better view please look here: https://jsfiddle.net/t305qap2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you give is a little far-fetched for me, but to achieve what you are asking, you can do one of two things:

**Wrap common code in a dedicated function**

```
var fade = function (element, duration) {
    element.fadeIn(duration);
}
```

This will let you call `fade(novy, 2000)` and exchange the underlying animation call as you need it.

**Store the function, not the result, in a variable**
You see, the reason why `var example = novy.fadeIn(2000)` isn't working is because it stores the *result* of calling `fadeIn` on that element, which is the element itself. `fadeIn` merely has the *side-effect* of animation. If you want to store a reference to the function instead of the result, JS allows this. See here:

```
var novyFader = novy.fadeIn // typeof novyFader === 'function' => true
novyFader.call(novy, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign the line to a function and store it as a variable. you can then change the function to a different value in the future

so create a clickFunction like this that returns a function

`var clickFunction = function() { return function(){novy.fadeIn(2000);} }`

Now change your on click to this

`$(document).on('click', clickFunction);`

At this time your code should work the same.

In the future you can assign clickFunction to some other function like

`clickFunction = function() { return function() {novy.fadeOut(2000);} }`

But you might also have to set the document.on callback again

HTH